# IntelliJ - Remote Scala Compile Server

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

**Is there a way to have a remote machine act as a Scala compile server using IntelliJ?**

IntelliJ has the option to use an external compile server, but this is machine local as far as I can tell.

I am wondering if this could be done with the help of sbt-server, but this is not a requirement.

Comment: I can't say for sure it isn't possible, but I've never seen the option exposed. You probably want to raise a feature request with JetBrains.

Comment: Feature Request:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8400

Comment: What is the advantage of using a remote machine? To reduce compile times by using a more powerful machine?

Comment: Having access to a more powerful box would be my use case. Let's say I'm out somewhere with my ultra thin laptop (with a fast network). Just writing code is of course no problem, but when it comes to compiling Scala (as a minimum to get correct feedback from the editor) , and running tests ans so on, it's a pain compared to my hexacore 32GB RAM workstation.

Comment: One solution would be to run a remote desktop to my workstation, but then it would have to be exposed (or on a VPN) and so on. The solution I'm thinking of here would be to spin up a high cpu AWS box for the time I need it.

Answer (score 1):

This use case is not supported by the compile server in the IntelliJ Scala plugin. It may be possible with the sbt 1.0 server functionality, but I believe it's not designed with this in mind either. It would require both the project files and the server to be available on the remote box, which is probably not what you had in mind.